# About the user account transfer on the Linux server

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

Suppose that I had a user named `user_A` in the original server `Linux_A`.
For now, I am told that I have a new user name `user_B`, which can be accessed by `ssh` from a `jumpserver` to the `Linux_A`.

What I want to do is to copy all in the `user_A` to the new `user_B`, to save some time needed to configure and compile existing software.
I think I can copy the `.bashrc` of `user_A` to `user_B` and do some modification.

But is there anything else I have to do?

Since I found when I tried to run some existing software, it can not succeed.

Or when I tried to compile some new software using `mpich` in `user_B`, it has some warnings,e.g. `f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘**user_A**/libraries/mpich/include’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]`.

1.How can I fix this type of problems other than rebuild all the thing.

2.By the way，is the hostname in `/etc/hostname` and in the `/etc/hosts` needed to be same. Since I found that when I tried to run previous compiled exe, it reported an error :

```
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(474)..............: 
MPID_Init(190).....................: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(89).................: 
MPID_nem_init(320).................: 
MPID_nem_tcp_init(173).............: 
MPID_nem_tcp_get_business_card(420): 
ckpt_restart(379)..................: gethostbyname failed,
```

but if I rebuild the `mpich`, and the `f951 warning` disappear. The compile and run of some `exe` also succeed

Comment: Which versions of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-133-generic x86_64)